# How to compress images in a folder so their total size to under a certain amount?

Tags: python, file, compression

I am writing a function for a program that takes a folder full of images (.jpg) and compresses them to under a certain size in bytes. I want the whole folder to be of a smaller size, so I want to limit each file's disk size. Here's what i have so far:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
maxSize = 750000 #750KB, 0.75MB
def file_size(fname):
    statinfo = os.stat(fname)
    return int(statinfo.st_size) ## bytes

def compressFiles(bool):
    if bool==True:
        for filename in os.listdir("."):
            if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
                print(filename,"Initial Size:",file_size(filename))
                while file_size(filename) >= maxSize:
                    foo = Image.open(filename)
                    foo.save(filename,quality=95)
                print(filename,"Final Size:",file_size(filename))
```

Here's what it outputs,

```
Initial Size: 120533
Final Size: 120533
Initial Size: 983463
```

... It then continues to open and close that next image with more than 750KB seemingly indefinitely.

Comment: I think this code assumes that opening and re-saving a jpg with 95% quality will reduce its file size. I don't think that's always true. I think it's possible for the file to remain the same size.

Comment: I doubt there's any shortcut to do this. That said, the best approach would probably be to try to speed it up what's being done. One way would be by minimizing I/O by reading and storing things in memory.